Catalyst rule return wrong logicalplan
  def apply(plan: LogicalPlan): LogicalPlan = {
    plan transform {
      case unresolvedRelation: UnresolvedRelation =>
        val tblSchemaName: Array[String] = unresolvedRelation.tableName.split("\\.")
        if (tblSchemaName.length == 1) return plan

        val schema = tblSchemaName.apply(0)
        val tblName = tblSchemaName.apply(1)
        for (ref <- this.refs) {
          if (tblName == ref.nqName) {
            return unresolvedRelation.copy(multipartIdentifier = Seq(schema.toUpperCase, tblName.toUpperCase), unresolvedRelation.options, unresolvedRelation.isStreaming)
          }
        }
        unresolvedRelation

      case unresolvedWith: UnresolvedWith =>
        val newCteRelations = unresolvedWith.cteRelations.map {
          case (aliasName, subqueryAlias) =>
            val newSubqueryAlias = apply(subqueryAlias).asInstanceOf[SubqueryAlias]
            (aliasName, newSubqueryAlias)
        }

        val modifiedCTEUnresolvedWith = unresolvedWith.copy(cteRelations = newCteRelations)
        modifiedCTEUnresolvedWith
        
      case otherPlan: LogicalPlan =>
        val newChildren = otherPlan.children.map(child => apply(child))
        val modified_plan = otherPlan.withNewChildren(newChildren)

        modified_plan
    }
  }
}

rules += UpperCaseTableRule(refs)

val optimizer = new RuleExecutor[LogicalPlan] {
    val batches = Seq(
      Batch("Rewrite", Once, rules.toList: _*)
    )
}

val logicalPlanRewrite = optimizer.execute(logicalPlan)

with the code above, what i want to achieve is to uppercase the names of the table if they are in the list.
the code can work with select statement, but when it comes to CTE, the unresolvedWith can return the correct CTE, but logicalPlanRewrite after the optimizer execute is still lower case.
for example
SELECT * FROM schema.t1 a JOIN schema.t2 b ON a.id = b.id
i can upper case to SCHEMA.T1 and SCHEMA.T2
but for CTE
 WITH x AS (SELECT * FROM schema.t1),y AS (SELECT * FROM schema.t2) " SELECT x.id, y.date FROM x JOIN y ON x.id = y.id
I can see that the code goes into unresolvedWith, and it becomes SCHEMA.T1 and SCHEMA.T2
but when the optimizer.execute return's, it goes back to lower case.
so in short, it only works in select statement not with CTE.
can anyone help me understand why?

How are you registering the plan?

@chris I am not sure what you are referring to. I use the rule to create rule executor, which is in the code snippet above.

sorry not a very helpfully phrased question, I'll make it an answer..

Optimizer.execute runs all batches with rules in addition to your plan, as such you need to understand where your rule should run.  A rule occurring after yours, due to CTE, is forcing the lowercase change, I'd assume to make sure it can lookup outer and inner references properly (canonical is lowercase).
As such you'd have to move to fully resolved lookups and run the rule as part of normal execution at an appropriate phase (see here for possible options).
It's quite possible that this rewriting of case also breaks Alias', the equal method relies on name equality.
If this is to make a case sensitive source work it may be better to do this at the source level rather than a plan, CSV header checks do this for instance.

I am not sure if that is the correct explaination, because if if there are other rule sapplied after my rule, the select statement won't change the table either. But it did. I print out the logicalplan and can see the table name to upper case.
it's only CTE that doesn't change.
when i say upper case, the code here is only a snippet, in real code I make sure  alias keeps the same, no upper, no lower.
i think it is a bug and i filed a jira, https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-49192
I listed the details in there.

to be clear, I'm not talking about you keeping the alias the same in the sql, but sparks other rules.  The code is open so you can look with a debug for where it's happening.

I went into where the rule is applied and i can see that my code path has been run.  I don't have enough knowledge to debug where the issue is in the source code. I can show you if you would kind enough to spare me sometime.  Please let me know. Thank you so so much.

I removed all other rules, only use my own rule. I will keep debugging...

follow up: i not only removed all other rules, i removed the rule executor completely, basically don't wrap the apply function in a ruleexecutor class, then the output comes as expected.
so i think the bug is in the ruleexecutor, because apply function's doesn't change, only moves out of the ruleexecutor class (derived class) and everything works as expected.
